# Is there a way to either save/copy/or email an entire iMessage conversation?

Tags: email, messages, copy-paste

Is there a one (or a simple) step process to either email myself, or cut/copy, an entire (like year long) iMessage conversation without having to buy an app/software or to go through and keep marking post groupings through "more" so I can send to my email?

I read about finding a hidden library folder in the question pertaining to the bulk download of pictures in iMessage. This did not really help.

Also, when I log into iMessage from my Macbook, my iPhone messages that predated the purchase do not show up. Even assuming it did, however, I still want to move the conversation out of iMessage so I can paste it into a word doc for posterity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bulk Download Pictures from Messages](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191869/bulk-download-pictures-from-messages)

Comment: You may want to check out this thread, which goes over downloading entire iMessage conversations (and photos) to the computer, broken out by date. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191869/bulk-download-pictures-from-messages/191874#191874

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I think that was more geared toward photos where I want to preserve the text in a document format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to back up my text messages from iPhone to computer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194990/how-to-back-up-my-text-messages-from-iphone-to-computer)

Comment: @gracey209 in the linked method, while the title is for how to save images, the HTML files that it also produces in the _export folder contain the conversations themselves :)

Comment: I think I was doing it wrong. I read the article linked to a comment and It has a different way of doing it than I have tried. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is the method I have used to extract my iMessage history (using a MacBook).

1. Find your chat history database `chat.db`. It is located at `~Library/Messages` which is accessible from Finder.
2. Use a Database Management System to extract the info you need. If you use macOS, sqlite3 is preinstalled in your system.

Open the database using `sqlite3 ~/Library/Messages/chat.db`.

See all your messages with:

```sql
SELECT
    datetime (message.date / 1000000000 + strftime ("%s", "2001-01-01"), 
    "unixepoch", "localtime") AS message_date,
    message.text,
    message.is_from_me,
    chat.chat_identifier
FROM
    chat
    JOIN chat_message_join ON chat.ROWID = chat_message_join.chat_id
    JOIN message ON chat_message_join.message_id = message.ROWID
ORDER BY
    message_date ASC;
```

You can save it as a CSV or Text file with this:

```
.mode csv
.out filename.csv
```

OR

```
.out filename.txt
your code
.quit
```

All credits to [Using SQL to Look Through All of Your iMessage Text Messages](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/05/22/search-imessage-sql/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm only aware of how to do this natively on macOS

1. Sign in to Messages on OS X
2. Select the conversation you want to save
3. File -> Print -> Save
4. (optional) Use whatever pdf editing software you choose to extract, copy, transform the PDF version of the conversation

There are third party solutions like [PhoneView by ecamm](https://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) to do this as well, but I don't know of an archive method on iOS. I'm a very happy customer of PhoneView - I sent them my money and have been satisfied by their continued updates of the product and the value.

Comment: Its on my iPhone not my Macbook. Although it is an iMessage it is not showing up on the OS X, I think (?) because I bought the Macbook after the last text was sent/rec'd.

Comment: @gracey209 I've had a newly wiped or set up mac download lots of past iMessage history. Hopefully this works for you if you set up a new user account.

Comment: But the iMessage conversation is on my phone and all that shows on iMessage on my Macbook are messages sent/rec'd after I set this machine up. I have no access to my phone's old messages. I am going to connect my phone again to my Macbook and try to capture it a different way. I'm clueless I think!

Comment: Furthermore, what if you don't have access to a mac where you can configure your iMessage account?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but people in the future may find my answer helpful

There is a software that has the ability to do this: [Imazing](https://imazing.com)

Here is a guide: https://imazing.com/guides/how-to-save-iphone-text-messages-sms-and-imessages-to-your-computer

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if it’s still available or compatible but in the past I used a program called Touch Copy purchased directly from the developer website- Wide Angle Software I think it was

Comment: I downloaded the free trial of this program, but it is not detecting my iPhone 11 Pro Max. Is it compatible with the latest iPhones?

Comment: Update: Finally, I downloaded another program (https://www.iphone-to-pc.com/how-transfer-messages-iphone-pc.html) to transfer text messages and iMessages from iPhone to my computer as PDF file. Then I forwarded the PDF to my gmail. Needed these messages for some legal matter. Just like TouchCopy it is also not free, but it did work for me.